# How to convert from TEXT to BLOB in SAP HANA database

Tags: sql, text, blob, hana, sql-types

I need to change the column "A" from data type TEXT to BLOB. Unfortunately I could not do it with this SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE "TEST" ALTER (A blob);
```

Which produces the following error:

> Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE "TEST" ALTER (A blob)' in 214 ms 508 µs .
>       SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: ALTER TABLE ALTER not allowed to change datatype or length of TEXT/SHORTTEXT

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating a new table and transferred the data with this SQL-statement:

```
insert into TEST_NEW
select CAST (A AS varchar) "A" 
from TEST
```

TEST_NEW column A is of type BLOB.